# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'testing.users' doesn't exist (Connection: mysql, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from

Tags: laravel, database, docker, testing, pestphp

I am trying to test signup for user in pest here is my pest code

```
test('signup user', function () {
    $response = $this->post('signup-user',[
        'email' => 'vishal444@gmail.com',
        'first_name' => 'vishal',
        'last_name' => 'singh',
        'password' => '111111',
        'confirm_password' => '111111'
    ]);
        
    $response->assertSessionHas('success', 'You have registered successfully');  
});
```

```
am getting this error
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'testing.users' doesn't exist (Connection: mysql, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = vishal444@gmail.com)   

  at D:\laravel-tailwind\laravelwithtailwind\tests\Feature\AppTest.php:36
     32▕         'password' => '111111',
     33▕         'confirm_password' => '111111'
     34▕     ]);
     35▕
  ➜  36▕     $response->assertSessionHas('success', 'You have registered successfully');
     37▕ });
     38▕
```

on docker all the containers are running well.and i have users table in my database,when i am testing someting related to data base or mysql am getting error

This is my `signup_user` function:

```
public function signupUser(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
        'first_name'=>'required', 
        'last_name'=>'required', 
        'password'=>'required|min:6|max:12', 
        'confirm_password'=>'required|min:6|max:12'
    ]);
    $user = new User(); 
    $user->email = $request->email; 
    $user->first_name = $request->first_name; 
    $user->last_name = $request->last_name; 
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->password); 
    $user->confirm_password = Hash::make($request->confirm_password);
```

I want to test this case:

```
test('user can signup', function () {
    $userData = [ 'email' => 'vishal123@gmail.com', 'first_name' => 'vishal', 'last_name' => 'singh', 'password' => '123123', 'confirm_password' => '123123', ];
    $this->post(route('signup-user'), $userData)
         ->assertSessionHas('success', 'You have registered successfully');
    $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', [ 'email' => 'vishal123@gmail.com', 'first_name' => 'vishal', 'last_name' => 'singh', ]);
});
```

Comment: Obviously there is no table `testing.users` in your database

Comment: @Vishal Kumar do you have that user "vishal444@gmail.com" created with a factory?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Sail creates a dedicated database named ***testing*** so that your tests are isolated from your main database and therefore don't interfere with the data within it (source: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/sail#running-tests). Sail also modifies the **phpunit.xml** file in your project to point at this ***testing*** database when running tests, by adding this line of code...

```
<env name="DB_DATABASE" value="testing"/>
```

The error message you reported stated `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'testing.users' doesn't exist`.

If you examine the ***testing*** database (e.g. using MySQL Workbench) you will see that it is an empty database and this is consistent with the error message you receive i.e. no `users` table exists within the ***testing*** database. The fact that you have a `users` table in your main database is irrelevant as your Pest test is not set to look at your main database.

One solution is to remove the above line of code from your **phpunit.xml** file (as you have noted in your answer). However, I would NOT recommend this approach as your tests will pollute your main database and may inadvertently delete data you wanted to keep.

Clearly, if the ***testing*** database is empty, then migrations need to be run to create the appropriate tables prior to the test running. Helpfully, Pest provides a configuration option which, when enabled, will reset the database prior to each test. This essentially calls `php artisan migrate:fresh` on your ***testing*** database.

The *best solution*, therefore, is to edit your **tests/Pest.php** file and uncomment the line in the `uses()` function which binds the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase` class to your test functions:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Test Case
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The closure you provide to your test functions is always bound to a specific PHPUnit test
| case class. By default, that class is "PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase". Of course, you may
| need to change it using the "uses()" function to bind a different classes or traits.
|
*/

uses(
    Tests\TestCase::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase::class,  // <- uncommented line
)->in('Feature');
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the Laravel documentation, Sail overrides the DB name you defined in the .env file when you run the tests. You need to remove the following line from your phpunit.xml file:  it is solved now thankyou

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).